# copy all rows from dataset for each unique value present in one column to new sheets in vba

Tags: excel, vba

Problem

1. I have a sheet in which first i have to filter the last column.
2. For each unique value  present in last column, I have to copy data from first column to last-1 column
3. Then I have to add new sheet and need to paste this data in new sheet.
4. I repeat same process 3 for each unique value present in last column. Like in last column is of language. so first sort this column. then copy and paste data for each language in new sheets.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are the column will change? what's the letter of the first and last column? #4 needs more details

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub LoopThroughAllItemsInFilters()

Range("G2", Range("G" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)).Select
Selection.Copy

Columns("L").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.Range("$L$1:$L$10000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

Dim ArrayDictionaryofItems As Object, Items As Variant, i As Long, Item As Variant

Set ArrayDictionaryofItems = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With ActiveSheet

'show autofilter if not already shown on all rows

If Not .AutoFilterMode Then .UsedRange.AutoFilter
If .Cells.AutoFilter Then .Cells.AutoFilter

'Create list of unique items in column G that get filled into ArrayDictionaryofItems
Dim annoying As Double

If Range("G3").Value <> "" Then
annoying = 2
Items = Range(.Range("L2"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp))

'Fills ArrayDictionaryofItems to the UBOUND (max) count of unique items in column L.

For i = 1 To UBound(Items, 1)
ArrayDictionaryofItems(Items(i, 1)) = 1
Next

Else

Item = Range("G2").Value
annoying = 1
End If

'Filter multiple items if annoying is set to equal 2 because G3 is blank
If annoying = 2 Then

For i = 1 To UBound(Items, 1)
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(i)
Next i

Sheets("DEFAULTERS").Select

Dim x As Double
x = 2

For Each Item In ArrayDictionaryofItems.keys
erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
'autofilter on column b with this driver
.UsedRange.AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:=Item

Columns("A:G").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets(x).Select
Columns("A:G").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("DEFAULTERS").Select

x = x + 1
Next Item
GoTo LINE99:
End If

'Filter a single item in column since G3 is blank and there is only one item in column G to filter
If annoying = 1 Then

Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Sheets("DEFAULTERS").Select

Item = Range("G2").Value
.UsedRange.AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:=Item
End If

Columns("A:G").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets(2).Select
Columns("A:G").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("DEFAULTERS").Select

End With

LINE99:
With ActiveSheet
If .AutoFilterMode Then .UsedRange.AutoFilter
End With

End Sub
```